# Solve this limit $\lim_{x\to0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How would I go about solving this limit ?

$$\lim_{x\to0} \,(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

I tried several times to solve it but I can't...

Comment: Hint: Write $x = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: think of the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Rather than saying "I tried several times to solve it but I can't..." which doesn't add anything, you could share what _exactly_ you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Using the binomial theorem with $x=1/n$, you have

$$(1+\frac1n)^n=1+\frac nn+\frac {n(n-1)}{2n^2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!n^3}+\cdots\le1+\frac11+\frac12+\frac1{3!}\cdots.$$
The sum is bounded and every term converges to the corresponding one in the last expression, that we can denote $e$.

Comment: Nice explanation

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Substitute $t = 1/x$ and remember a famous limit

Answer (score 3):

Hint: rewrite this as $\exp(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x})$ as apply l'Hopital.

Comment: using l'Hoptial's rule depends on the derivative of exp/log, which in some constructions depends on the value of this very limit. So this could be a circular argument.